# AngularJS set limitTo to unlimited in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need users to be able to change how many entries they should see that the reason I need to use `limitTo` in `ng-repeat` but I also need to be able to let them see all the entries so how do I set it to unlimited?

example:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | limitTo:limitPeople">
    <!--- som entry -->
</div>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Do you have some code we can see? Also why do you want to 'make `limitTo` unlimited' - you could just not include `limitTo`.

Comment: Added some code. the reason to add `limitTo` is as I mentioned that user should be able to set the limit if he wants to.

Comment: It should be more understandable from the beginning, but If you provide more context inside the ng-repeat and maybe include a jsfiddle or something, it should be more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[limitTo Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

If u change the value to undefined the filter should not apply so everything should be shown.

> If limit is undefined, the input will be returned unchanged.